# Is there a program that will generate a JSON config file based on a template and variables?

Tags: json, automation, sass

I have a project where I make JSON files periodically and it would be great to be able to template a JSON file and then just enter params and a complete JSON file is outputted. Imagine sass for JSON. Any programs like that out there?

Comment: sass for JSON is.. surprise! - Javascript

Comment: Yeah this was my fallback, just didn't want to have to write the whole compilation script myself. I guess it's not a big task. Cheers.

Comment: What backend are you going to use to populate the template with actual data?